# What are the compact elements in the domain of functions on the Interval Domain, [D,D]?

Tags: ct.category-theory, approximation-theory

Take the interval domain $D = \{[a,b]| a \le b, \in \mathbb{R}\}$, ordered by reverse inclusion.

Next, take the domain of functions $D' = \{f| f:D \rightarrow D \}$, ordered as follows $f \le g$ if $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x$ in $D$.

What are the compact/finite elements in $D'$?

The definition of compact/finite is given as follows.

Def:
An element $x$ is way below an element $y$, if, for every directed set $D$ with supremum such that

$y \sqsubseteq \sup D$

there is some element $d$ in $D$ such that

$x \sqsubseteq d$.

Then one also says that $x$ approximates $y$ and writes

$x \ll y$.

This does imply that

$x \sqsubseteq y$,

Elements with the property:

$x \ll x$

are called compact.

Comment: If $f:D\to D$ then an argument of $f$ is an interval, not a real number.

Comment: I am afraid, the order on $D'$ still is not correctly defined.